# .htaccess RedirectMatch conditional regex fails

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Good evening dear fellow coders,

I am trying to handle urls without file extensions that are more readable to average internet users using a .htaccess redirect, like `http://example.com/file` to `http://example.com/file.php` (with or without query)

Unfortunately I am not able to use mod_rewrite, but although redirect does work, it seems not to be able to handle my request properly.

To handle any given URL I tried using

```
RedirectMatch ^/(?(?=.*\.php(?i).*)|(\w+)(.*)) /$1.php$2
```

And

```
RedirectMatch ^/.*\.php(?i).*|(\w+)(.*) /$1.php$2
```

As well as using `$2` and `$3`, assuming the behaviour might extract the first pattern contrary to every knowledge.

It should extract characters and numbers for `$1` and everything else for `$2` (starting with `?` for queries etc.) unless it contains the file extension .php.

Validating the regex with https://regex101.com/r/zF2bV9/2 everything should work fine, but implementing one of these lines to the `.htaccess` the filename will replace any given file with ".php" (as in `http://example.com/.php`) and obviously produce an error of a non-existing file.

What am I missing about the code or the redirect functionality?

Comment: "and everything else for $2 (starting with ? for queries etc.)" - just to note, `RedirectMatch` matches against the URL-path only. You can't match the query string. But neither do you need to, as it will be passed through to the target unaltered.

Comment: @w3dk once it happend to work properly with `RedirectMatch ^/(\w+)(.*) /$1.php$2` in another server configuration, but now this will result in a infinite loop. do i get you right, that $2 is uneccessary at all? unfortunately i cannot test it while the first problem occurs though.

Comment: The particular URLs could affect this, but not the "server configuration". That directive would always result in an infinite loop for a URL like `/file`. Yes, `$2` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
RedirectMatch ^/([^.]+)$ /$1.php
```

This matches the URL providing there is not already a dot (ie. `.php`) in the URL. And so prevents a redirect loop.

As mentioned in comments, you don't need to do anything specific with the query string, providing you want it passed through to the destination unaltered. The query string is not present in the URL-path that the `RedirectMatch` directive matches against anyway. So, any *manipulation* of the query string would *require* mod_rewrite.

Comment: Unfortunately his doesn´t work for me either. I get a 404 error with my custom error message. But the address-line stays as typed, what i find to be confusing. Maybe I get the whole redirect-thing wrong?

Thanks for the query topic though!

Comment: If the "address-line stays as typed" then the above `RedirectMatch` (mod_alias) directive isn't doing anything. What URL are you requesting? Do you have any other directives in `.htaccess`? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? Presumably this directive is going in a `.htaccess` file in the document root? Presumably these "urls without file extensions" are just a shortcut for your users? Your application is still using the full with-extension URLs?